# ODE satisfied by directional derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the ODE $$y'(t)=f(y(t)),$$
with initial condition $y(0)=y_0$. 
Assume that $y(t)=F(t,y_0)$ is a solution to this ODE.

I need to find the equations that are satisfied by $\nabla_{y_0}F$ and by $\nabla^2_{y_0}F$ by considering one and two derivatives with respect to $y_0$.

 I am a bit confused about this. Does $\nabla_{y_0}F$ the directional derivative? I am really not sure how to start the problem.

Comment: I should also mention that $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x(t) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ for all $t$ and that $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Is it the Levi-Civita connection? Notation looks like it, but the context is a bit off.

Comment: No, this is from a course about ODEs that I am studying. It doesn't include differential geometry or more advanced subjects.

Comment: $\nabla_{y} F$ probably just means the gradient of $F(t,y)$ with respect to $y$, i.e., the vector $$(\partial F/\partial y_1, \dots, \partial F/\partial y_n).$$ (Assuming that $y \in \mathbf{R}^n$.)

Comment: Yes, that would make sense. I am still not sure how to approach the problem though.

Comment: What do you know about $f$? We need want it to be $C^1$ in order for the flux to be differentiable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $f \in C^1$ (if not then your problem might not be well-defined) then we can interchange $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}$ and $D_y$. Note how I use $D_y$ and not the transpose $\nabla_y$ (makes things easier). Use that $F$ satisfies the ODE and then apply the chain rule.
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} D_y F(t, y) = D_y \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}  F(t, y) = D_y f(F(t, y)) = Df(F(t, y))D_yF(t, y)
$$
Transpose everything to get your desired equation. This of course depends on $F$ and is a linear ODE where the representing matrix depends on time. Do not expect to be able to solve this for $D_yF(t,y)$.

I hope that this is what you meant by your question. I am sure that you can proceed to find the equation for $\nabla^2$.